# Ventajas/Desventajas sobre los Bit Fileds C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

He estado tratando de optimizar uno de mis proyectos en todas las áreas que puedo, y hace poco me entere sobre la existencia de los Bit-Fields, y he estado practicando con esto para implementarlo en mi proyecto (los quiero usar para ahorrar mucha memoria en mis `structs`).

La ventaja de esto es muy clara, puedes combinar el espacio desperdiciado entre variables para juntarlos y usar cada bit posible. Lo que se me hizo raro es que se habla muy poco de este tema, fue pura casualidad encontrarme con esto de los Bit-Fields, por lo que decidí hacer todas las pruebas que se me ocurrieron para buscar un aspecto negativo. Intente medir la velocidad al crear, modificar y copiar estos Bit-Fields a comparación de las variables comunes (int, floats, chars, etc). Decidí hacer pruebas de velocidad, y al crear, modificar y copiar los Bit-Fields entre si es casi lo mismo que hacerlo con tipos de variable comunes (o al menos con las pruebas que hice).

No soy experto en C++ y estoy aprendiendo a hacer mis proyectos de forma optimizada, por eso les pido ayuda para saber en que escenarios vale la pena utilizar los Bit-Fields y si tienen alguna desventaja importante que deba tomar en cuenta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> La ventaja de esto es muy clara, puedes combinar el espacio desperdiciado entre variables para juntarlos y usar cada bit posible

Eso no tiene por qué ser una ventaja. A ver, los que diseñan la arquitectura de los ordenadores no son tontos, y los que programan compiladores menos todavía.

Hoy en día lo que prima es la velocidad de acceso y el acceso a memoria se hace por palabras, no por bits, juntando eso tenemos que el acceso a una palabra completa será más rápido que el acceso a una parte de esa palabra.

Los microprocesadores se optimizan para trabajar con datos *estándar*, luego moverse en ese espectro suele dar mejores resultados que hacer encaje de bolillos.

> Lo que se me hizo raro es que se habla muy poco de este tema

Por algo será, ¿no? Si tan relevante fuese el tema actualmente todo el mundo hablaría de ello. Esta práctica vivió su apogeo hace, no se, como unos 20-30 años, cuando los equipos apenas manejaban unos pocos KB o MB de memoria. Hoy en día su uso queda relegado a software antiguo, a aplicaciones que corren en sistemas con muy pocos recursos, y a aplicaciones hechas por programadores que reman en otra dirección

> Intente medir la velocidad al crear, modificar y copiar estos Bit-Fields a comparación de las variables comunes

El tiempo de creación será básicamente el mismo porque no creas nada, simplemente reservas palabras de memoria. Si la reserva es en la pila, el coste tiende a 0, si es en el *heap*, lo costoso ahí es buscar un hueco donde entre el objeto, el resto es *pecata minuta*, es decir, que el objeto ocupe 10 bytes más o menos no supone diferencia alguna.

En cuanto al copiado, lo mismo, aquí quizás sí debería ser ligeramente más rápido tu programa ya que tendrá que copiar menos bytes, pero hablamos de eso, de unos pocos bytes. Tu mismo dices estás reconociendo que no hay apenas diferencias. Cachés y DMA hacen que esos datos fluyan a gran velocidad.

> estoy aprendiendo a hacer mis proyectos de forma optimizada

Si quieres hacer las cosas bien tienes que dejar las cosas claras: Tu proyecto, antes de empezar a escribir una sola línea de código, tiene que estar especificado (alcance, limitaciones, requisitos, ...). Ese documento será la hoja de ruta de tu proyecto, y será el árbitro que dirá si tu programa cumple o no cumple. Si cumple no hay que optimizarlo más, ya funciona tal cual se ha especificado ... si no cumple entonces será cuando haya que optimizarlo.

Dicho con un ejemplo: si tu programa tiene que ser capaz de encontrar un registro en 0.1s y tarda 0.08s, no hace falta tocar nada. Optimizarlo para arañarle una centésima de segundo más no tiene sentido:

- No va a ser perceptible para nadie, nadie se va a beneficiar de ese esfuerzo extra
- Los cambios que implica pueden afectar a otras partes del programa
- Las optimizaciones suelen ir en contra de la legibilidad del código

Y ya, para finalizar, tratando un poco el tema por encima, yo el panorama lo veo así:

Ventajas:

- Empaquetas información: Puedes hacer que los campos booleanos ocupen únicamente un bit. En sistemas embebidos con pocos recursos es una herramienta muy util

Desventajas:

- Difícil de depurar: Dado que varias propiedades ocupan la misma palabra en memoria, el proceso de depuración se complica. Ya no te basta con, por ejemplo, poner un punto de parada en esa posición de memoria para ver quien la está modificando.
- Difícil de gestionar: Empaquetar información es como hacer las maletas y guardarlas en el coche. Está claro que cuanto mejor utilices el espacio, más maletas te van a entrar y menos te vas a mover ... pero también te requiere más esfuerzo y tiempo conseguir esa *perfección*. En programación esto se sigue cumpliendo. Empaquetar la información requiere un esfuerzo extra.
- Innecesario: Volviendo al símil de las maletas, en los equipos actuales el empaquetado sería como intentar encajar perfectamente 4 maletas en una nave espacial del tamaño de un continente. En serio, salvo que tu aplicación consuma gigas y gigas de memoria, no vas a conseguir ningún beneficio que los usuarios puedan experimentar
- Más lento: Una operación sobre la memoria siempre será más rápido que una operación sobre la memoria y una operación binaria. Incluso si lo que haces es dividir un `struct` en campos de bits, las operaciones que el programa tiene que hacer para manipular esa información serán sensiblemente más lentas que recuperar la palabra de memoria directamente
- Incompatibilidad binaria: Mucho cuidado al compartir información entre aplicaciones de diferentes arquitecturas. Esto normalmente suele ser problemático siempre, pero en tu caso adquiere una nueva dimensión. Al tener los bits empaquetados, un cambio de big-endian a little-endian, por ejemplo, provocacía que cada arquitectura acceda a bits de propiedades que no son las esperadas ... un error silencioso pero bastante desagradable

Answer (score 3):

Hay muchos temas que tratar en tu pregunta, vayamos por partes.

---

Los campos de bits (bitfields) son una funcionalidad poco usada en C++ no por temas de rendimiento si no por temas de compatibilidad. Muchas de las operaciones que se hacen sobre campos de bits dependen de la implementación del compilador:

- Mientras que el overflow y underflow de datos está perfectamente definido y controlado en datos fundamentales, cuando se asigna un valor a un campo de bits, el valor asignado dependerá de implementación si dicho campo no puede almacenar el valor (estándar de C++ sección *7.6.19.4 Operadores de asignación y asignación compuesta*):

  ```
  struct S { int a:3; int b:1; int c:4; } s;

  s.a = 8; // Valor indeterminado
  ```
- La disposición (posición y alineamiento) de los campos de bits en un objeto es dependiente de implementación (estándar de C++ sección *11.4.9.1 Campos de bits)* por lo que su representación binaria puede cambiar entre arquitecturas, entre compiladores o entre ambas cosas.
- Acceder de manera concurrente a dos elementos de un campo de bits que comparten espacio de memoria es un comportamiento indefinido.

Por otro lado, no se puede obtener la dirección de memoria de un elemento de un campo de bits, ni se puede obtener una referencia no constante al mismo. Tampoco existen valores del lado derecho (RValues) de tipo campo de bits, éstos se promocionan antes de cualquier operación (estándar de C++ sección *7.2.1.6 Categorías de valores*).

---

Así pues, los campos de bits pueden ser incómodos de usar, dar lugar a comportamientos inesperados y en consecuencia ser propensos a errores. Por ello te aconsejo que no los uses a no ser que trabajes en plataformas con estrictas limitaciones de memoria. No caigas en las [optimizaciones prematuras](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/premature_optimization), optimiza el código cuando sea necesario y donde sea necesario.

> Intente medir la velocidad al crear, modificar y copiar estos Bit-Fields a comparación de las variables comunes (int, floats, chars, etc). Decidí hacer pruebas de velocidad, y al crear, modificar y copiar los Bit-Fields entre si es casi lo mismo que hacerlo con tipos de variable comunes (o al menos con las pruebas que hice).

Por muy listos que nos creamos como programadores, el compilador siempre va a ser más listo que nosotros; no encontrarás diferencias significativas entre usar un campo de bits y no usarlo porque el compilador generará un código óptimo para cualquiera de los casos, así que insisto: no uses campos de bits a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario.